# How to use sigwaitinfo() in C

Tags: c, signals

I'm trying to make the process to wait for a signal from his son. It seems to not be working. I'm not into C this much so my code can be horrible. Here's the code:

Parents code:

```
sigemptyset (&mask);
sigaddset (&mask, SIGUSR1);
sigprocmask (SIG_SETMASK, &mask, NULL); 
sigwaitinfo(&mask, &info);
sigprocmask (SIG_UNBLOCK, &mask, NULL);
```

Children code:

```
kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
```

Comment: When do you run the child process?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. There's nothing obviously wrong with what you posted.

Comment: Here's [a fiddle](https://ideone.com/U4osK9) that shows this technique working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Examine the following example program, **example.c**:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

static inline const char *signal_name(const int signum)
{
    switch (signum) {
    case SIGINT:  return "SIGINT";
    case SIGHUP:  return "SIGHUP";
    case SIGTERM: return "SIGTERM";
    case SIGQUIT: return "SIGQUIT";
    case SIGUSR1: return "SIGUSR1";
    case SIGUSR2: return "SIGUSR2";
    default:      return "(unnamed)";
    }    
}

int main(void)
{
    sigset_t  mask;
    siginfo_t info;
    pid_t     child, p;
    int       signum;    

    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGINT);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGHUP);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGTERM);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGQUIT);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGUSR1);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGUSR2);
    if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, NULL) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot block SIGUSR1: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    child = fork();
    if (child == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot fork a child process: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } else
    if (!child) {
        /* This is the child process. */
        printf("Child process %d sleeping for 3 seconds ...\n", (int)getpid());
        fflush(stdout);
        sleep(3);

        printf("Child process %d sending SIGUSR1 to parent process (%d) ...\n", (int)getpid(), (int)getppid());
        fflush(stdout);
        kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);

        printf("Child process %d exiting.\n", (int)getpid());
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    /* This is the parent process. */
    printf("Parent process %d is waiting for signals.\n", (int)getpid());
    fflush(stdout);

    while (1) {

        signum = sigwaitinfo(&mask, &info);
        if (signum == -1) {

            /* If some other signal was delivered to a handler installed
               without SA_RESTART in sigaction flags, it will interrupt
               slow calls like sigwaitinfo() with EINTR error. So, those
               are not really errors. */
            if (errno == EINTR)
                continue;

            printf("Parent process: sigwaitinfo() failed: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        if (info.si_pid == child)
            printf("Parent process: Received signal %d (%s) from child process %d.\n", signum, signal_name(signum), (int)child);
        else
        if (info.si_pid)
            printf("Parent process: Received signal %d (%s) from process %d.\n", signum, signal_name(signum), (int)info.si_pid);
        else
            printf("Parent process: Received signal %d (%s).\n", signum, signal_name(signum));
        fflush(stdout);

        /* Exit when SIGUSR1 received from child process. */
        if (signum == SIGUSR1 && info.si_pid == child) {
            printf("Parent process: Received SIGUSR1 from child.\n");
            break;
        }

        /* Also exit if Ctrl+C pressed in terminal (SIGINT). */
        if (signum == SIGINT && !info.si_pid) {
            printf("Parent process: Ctrl+C pressed.\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("Reaping child process...\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    do {
        p = waitpid(child, NULL, 0);
        if (p == -1) {
            if (errno == EINTR)
                continue;
            printf("Parent process: waitpid() failed: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    } while (p != child);

    printf("Done.\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compile and run it using e.g.

```
gcc -Wall -O2 example.c -o example
./example
```

You can increment the time the child process sleeps, if you want to externally inject a signal to the parent process. If the parent process ID is say 24316, you can send it eg. a SIGHUP signal via `kill -HUP 24316` from another terminal. If you run the example interactively as shown above, you can also cause the terminal to send a SIGINT signal to the process by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Observations:

- `sigprocmask()` is used to block the interesting signals in the parent process before `fork()`, to ensure that the parent process is able to catch the signal. It also means the signals are blocked in the child process.

  If the signals were blocked in the parent process *after* the `fork()`, then it would be possible for the child process to send the signal before the parent process is ready to catch it. In the case of SIGUSR1, the [default action](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) would terminate the parent process.
- `signal_name()` function only exists to pretty-print the signal name.

  It is marked `static inline` mostly so that us human developers understand it is a helper function visible only in the current compilation unit. For the compiler, `static` says the function is only visible in the current compilation unit, and `inline` says the compiler is free to incorporate its functionality in whoever calls it, rather than calls to a named function.

  The return value is `const char *`, because the function returns a string literal.
- `fork()` can return -1 if an error occurs.
- `fork()` returns twice. In the parent process, the return value is positive; the child process ID. In the child process, the return value is zero.

  The new child process is essentially a snapshot copy of the parent process. The order in which they start executing is basically random: they can run concurrently, both at the same time; or one can run first, with the other slightly later on.  Computers are so fast nowadays that concepts like "soon enough" measured in microseconds may still lead to bugs, so we need to be careful and understand the bigger picture. Hence, setting the signal mask early.
- Many functions return -1 or NULL if an error occurs, with `errno` set to indicate the error.  When writing code, you should always implement the error checks. They allow you to detect logical and functional errors while testing the code. In the exceedingly rare case where they "slow" anything down, you can always remove them after profiling and testing.  In practice, they're well worth it, every single time; if not for anything else, for catching incorrect programmer expectations.
- See [`man 2 sigaction`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) and [`man 7 signal`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) to see which signals fill in which `siginfo_t` fields, and how you can determine whether a signal was sent by another process (via `kill()` or `sigqueue()`), raised, triggered by a POSIX timer, et cetera.
- See the while loop with [`waitpid()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) on how to reap a child process. We could use the second parameter, pointer to int, and `WIFEXITED()`/`WEXITSTATUS()` and `WIFSIGNALED()`/`WTERMSIG()` to examine the exit status of the child process.  I did not bother, because the child process always returns `EXIT_SUCCESS`, which in POSIXy systems is 0.
- Learn to design and build programs from modular pieces, rather than aggregating everything in one pile and then try to sort it out.

  We could make the above example easier to grasp, if we split the child process operations to a separate function.

  Splitting into functions is not a goal, however: it is just a tool, used to make the code as simple and easy to understand and maintain as possible. We humans have limited brain power, but if we *focus* it correctly, we can create amazing stuff.
- Good comments are at least as important as good code is.

  Comments that describe what the code is doing are less than worthless. We can read the code, to see what it does.  What the code does not tell us is *why* the programmer wrote the code: what the purpose of the code is, what the logical model or algorithm the code tries to implement is.

  There are only five comments in the example program. This is not enough; but even after a couple of decades of writing code professionally, I am struggling with writing better comments. (Mostly, it is difficult to describe the mental structures I think with, using linear text. It is like having learned a language by reading, and not being able to pronounce or understand the spoken one.) If I had learned to write good comments as I learned to write good code, I would have saved a LOT of effort.

  I recommend you avoid the frustration, and spend the effort of learning how to write good comments from the get go.

---

Here is another example, **example2.c**, that does a bit more signal ping-pong between the parent and the child process:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

static inline const char *signal_name(const int signum)
{
    switch (signum) {
    case SIGINT:  return "SIGINT";
    case SIGHUP:  return "SIGHUP";
    case SIGTERM: return "SIGTERM";
    case SIGQUIT: return "SIGQUIT";
    case SIGUSR1: return "SIGUSR1";
    case SIGUSR2: return "SIGUSR2";
    default:      return "(unnamed)";
    }    
}

int child_process(const pid_t parent, sigset_t *mask)
{
    siginfo_t    info;
    int          signum;

    printf("Child: sleep(1).\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);

    printf("Child: Sending SIGUSR1 to parent.\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    kill(parent, SIGUSR1);

    printf("Child: Waiting for a SIGUSR2 from parent.\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    while (1) {
        signum = sigwaitinfo(mask, &info);
        if (signum == SIGUSR2 && info.si_pid == parent) {
            printf("Child: Received SIGUSR2 from parent.\n");
            break;
        }

        if (info.si_pid == parent)
            printf("Child: Received %s from parent.\n", signal_name(signum));
        else
        if (info.si_pid)
            printf("Child: Received %s from process %d.\n", signal_name(signum), (int)info.si_pid);
        else
            printf("Child: Received %s.\n", signal_name(signum));
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    printf("Child: Sending SIGHUP to parent.\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    kill(parent, SIGHUP);

    printf("Child: sleep(1).\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);

    printf("Child: Done.\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void parent_process(const pid_t child, sigset_t *mask)
{
    siginfo_t  info;
    int        signum;

    printf("Parent: Waiting for a SIGUSR1 from child.\n");
    while (1) {
        signum = sigwaitinfo(mask, &info);
        if (signum == SIGUSR1 && info.si_pid == child) {
            printf("Parent: Received SIGUSR1 from child.\n");
            break;
        }

        if (info.si_pid == child)
            printf("Parent: Received %s from child.\n", signal_name(signum));
        else
        if (info.si_pid)
            printf("Parent: Received %s from process %d.\n", signal_name(signum), (int)info.si_pid);
        else
            printf("Parent: Received %s.\n", signal_name(signum));
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    printf("Parent: sleep(1).\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);

    printf("Parent: Sending SIGUSR2 to child.\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    kill(child, SIGUSR2);

    printf("Parent: Waiting for a SIGHUP from child.\n");
    while (1) {
        signum = sigwaitinfo(mask, &info);
        if (signum == SIGHUP && info.si_pid == child) {
            printf("Parent: Received SIGHUP from child.\n");
            break;
        }

        if (info.si_pid == child)
            printf("Parent: Received %s from child.\n", signal_name(signum));
        else
        if (info.si_pid)
            printf("Parent: Received %s from process %d.\n", signal_name(signum), (int)info.si_pid);
        else
            printf("Parent: Received %s.\n", signal_name(signum));
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    sigset_t  mask;
    pid_t     child, p;
    int       status;

    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGINT);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGHUP);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGTERM);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGQUIT);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGUSR1);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGUSR2);
    if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, NULL) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot block SIGUSR1: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    child = fork();
    if (child == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot fork a child process: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } else
    if (!child)
        return child_process(getppid(), &mask);
    else
        parent_process(child, &mask);

    printf("Parent: Reaping child process.\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    do {
        p = waitpid(child, &status, 0);
        if (p == -1) {
            if (errno == EINTR)
                continue;
            printf("Parent: waitpid() error: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    } while (p != child);

    if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
        switch (WEXITSTATUS(status)) {
        case EXIT_SUCCESS:
            printf("Parent: Child reaped; EXIT_SUCCESS.\n");
            break;
        case EXIT_FAILURE:
            printf("Parent: Child reaped; EXIT_FAILURE.\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Parent: Child reaped; exit status %d.\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
        }
    } else
    if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
        printf("Parent: Child died from signal %d.\n", WTERMSIG(status));
    } else {
        printf("Parent: Child process was lost unexpectedly.\n");
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You can experiment with the signals, and the child exit status, as this one reports that as well.

To develop a signal ping-pong scheme, I suggest writing it out as a timeline first. For example:

```
Child sleeps for a second  ┆  Parent waits for SIGUSR1
Child sends SIGUSR1        ┆
Child waits for SIGUSR2    ┆  Parent receives SIGUSR1
                           ┆  Parent sleeps for a second
                           ┆  Parent sends SIGUSR2
Child receives SIGUSR2     ┆  Parent waits for SIGHUP
Child sends SIGHUP         ┆
Child sleeps for a second  ┆  Parent receives SIGHUP
Child exits                ┆
                           ┆  Parent reaps child
                           ┆  Parent exits
```

Such a diagram helps writing the code, checking if output matches the expectations (noting that not all events are well ordered), and checking if the code implements the diagram correctly. It should be part of the program documentation, too.

Comment: If I want to receive several signals from the parent process, is the method the same? Would I just have to copy and paste the code whenever I want to receive the signal? If that's correct, is it enough with the while loop or the whole code with sigprocmask...?

Comment: @Alejandro: You can use the same method. If the process does other real work, and signals are handled asynchronously (say, changes a flag or similar), then you use signal handlers instead.

Comment: The while loop seems to not have an end... I implemented the code on my program and the code after the while loop doesn't run. I do the kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1) on the sons code. Could something be wrong in that loop?

Comment: @Alejandro: `break` breaks out of a `while` loop. I added a second example, extended from the first, to show a bit more complex example of sending and receiving signals between a parent and a child process.  Note that both examples are written to ignore extraneous signals: they verify both the signal and the sender.

Answer (score 1):

From [this link](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigwaitinfo.2.html):

> `sigwaitinfo()` suspends execution of the calling thread until one of
>   the signals in set is pending (If one of the signals in set is
>   already pending for the calling thread, `sigwaitinfo()` will return
>   immediately.)
>
> `sigwaitinfo()` removes the signal from the set of pending signals
>   and returns the signal number as its function result.  If the info 
>   argument is not `NULL`, then the buffer that it points to is used to
>   return a structure of `type siginfo_t` containing
>   information about the signal.
>
> If multiple signals in set are pending for the caller, the signal
>   that is retrieved by s`igwaitinfo()` is determined according to the
>   usual ordering rules.

I was wondering the difference with `sigwait` and here it is

> The `sigwait()` function suspends execution of the calling thread
>   until one of the signals specified in the signal set set becomes
>   pending. The function accepts the signal (removes it from the
>   pending list ofsignals), and returns the signal number in sig.
>
> The operation of `sigwait()` is the same as `sigwaitinfo`, except
>   that:
>
> - `sigwait()` returns only the signal number, rather than a `siginfo_t`
>      structure describing the signal.
> - The return values of the two functions are different.

The syntax for the functions is:

```
int sigwaitinfo(const sigset_t *set, siginfo_t *info);
```